# Send updates or progress in Spring Controller before response

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, reactjs

I have a form that allows users to upload CSV files which subsequently uses Superagent to make a POST call to a controller in the backend which parses through the file and executes batch inserts into our tables. I would like to implement a progress bar on the front-end side that listens for updates from the controller to show the progress of the parsing/inserts. On the front end I'm using React and currently making the call like this:

```
  request.post('/api/uploadFile')
        .send(csvFile)
        .on('progress', function(e) {
            console.log('Percentage done: ', e.percent);
        })
        .end((err, resp) => {
            if (err) {
                $("#loading").hide();
                console.log("Error in file upload");
                console.error(err);
                alert("Failed to upload. " + err + "\n (" + err.status + ") " + resp.text);
            }
            else {
                $("#loading").hide();
                console.log(resp);
                alert("Success. " + resp.text);
                return resp;
            }
        });
      }
```

The progress event listener automatically shows 100% as soon as I send the file, which is incorrect (the sending appears to be instant but it doesn't actually know how much is reached from the other end until there's a response). On the backend I have a controller like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/api/uploadFile", method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public @ResponseBody ResponseEntity<String> handleFileUpload(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file){
        if (!checkCSV(file)) {
            return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.UNPROCESSABLE_ENTITY).body("Not CSV");
        }
        if (file.isEmpty()) {
            return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.UNPROCESSABLE_ENTITY).body("File is empty");
        }
        MySQLAccess db = new MySQLAccess();
        File fileToParse = convertToFile(file);

        /* Call helper function that parse CSV file & execute batch inserts & creates join tables */

        return ResponseEntity.ok("File was uploaded.");
    }
```

I would like to interleave progress status (which I can set) in my controller that would update the frontend regarding which step the file upload is at: the parsing/batch inserts/table creations, etc. I would like to do this because my app is currently deployed on Heroku and I keep hitting request timeouts because the file upload process takes around 1 minute, which is over the 30 second window Heroku sets for H12 request timeouts if it doesn't receive a single byte back to the client (I'm assuming if I'm sending back updates it might prevent these timeouts?). Does anyone have any suggestions on how to send updates from my controller to update the progress before the response is sent back?